# How do I iterate over columns in python to find a match for key values?

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

[image]

I want to iterate over df2(LocationID) to find the corresponding Long and Lat coordinates for locationID's in df1. Match is based on on PULocation(df1)=LocationID(df2); DOLocation(df1)=LocationID(df2).The resulting new dataframe generates the coordinates for PULocation and DOLocation. It looks like the table labeled NewDF. My data is very large and I'm looking for an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
new_df = df1.merge(df2.rename({'LocationID': 'PULocationID', 'Longtitude': 'PU_longtitue', 'Latitude': 'PU_latitude'}, axis=1), how='left')\
.merge(df2.rename({'LocationID': 'DOLocationID', 'Longtitude': 'DO_longtitue', 'Latitude': 'DO_latitude'}, axis=1), how='left')
```

After that, all that supposed to be left is to re-arrange the columns in `new_df` as you want.

Comment: As you can see the locationID in the df2 start with 1 and that of df1 start with 161. The goal is to filter for the LocationID in df2 that corresponds to that in df1, then use lats and long in df to match ID's in df1 in new dataframe

Comment: @sly44 If the numbers don't match, how do you know which row in `df2` fits each row in `df1`?

Comment: The rows in each df are not the same, since df2 contains just a list of locations and their coordinates, whereas the df1 records movements from one place to another. meaning a person can have multiple records in df1.